# Can't import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, native, android-support-library

Hi What happen in my android studio i need to use ContextCompat for checkSelfPermission so that i need to import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat but android studio can't find in this Lib

[image]

from this picture you can see this Lib only have media and R but not have content so i have already add implementation in app/build.gradle

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
```

so what i missing here?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: Just Invalidate cache and restart then it's fine, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your support library to latest version `28.0.0-alpha1` and Try `Build -> clean Project` or `Invalidate cache and restart` as android studio might not be able to clear old cache.

Comment: Just Invalidate cache and restart then it's fine, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `google()` under `repositories` of `allprojects` like this in your project level `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()

        // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must
        // instead use:
        //
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps